# HTML page breaks when resize

Tags: html, css

My issue is that I made a pretty big html page oriented on 125% browser zoom,
however when I put it in 100% all the position's and margin's start to change, thus breaking my html page awfully.

```
html { width: 100%; height: 280%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { margin: 0 ; padding: 0; background: url(Photoshop/img/header_bg.png),url(Photoshop/img/full_bg.png); background-size: 1600px 655px,cover; background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat; }
header h1 { float: left; margin: 28px 0 0 220px; }
nav ul { list-style-type: none; float: right; }
nav li { float: right; margin: 53px 20px 50px 0px; text-transform: uppercase; }
```

What is the best way to fix the problem, without change every single piece of css code( margins position top right, e.t.c).

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: It is too long, i'll send just a part.

tml{
                width: 100%;
                height: 280%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
             
}
body {
  
 margin: 0 ;

 padding: 0;
 background: url(Photoshop/img/header_bg.png),url(Photoshop/img/full_bg.png);
 background-size: 1600px 655px,cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;

 
 
}
header h1 {
float: left;
margin: 28px 0 0 220px;



}

nav ul {

 list-style-type: none;
 float: right;
   
  nav li{


float: right;
margin: 53px 20px 50px 0px;
text-transform: uppercase;

Comment: Update your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have notoced you are using fixed values in your margins. 
Try to use presentage, if that dont work use the @media in css to handle different sizes.

Margin example - margin-top: 10%;